# Bad response code when uploading image with Twitpic API

Tags: iphone, objective-c, twitter

Can anybody familiar with the source code for uploading image to Twitter using "Twitpic api" please tell why I get a 0 response code when I am trying to upload an image?

Here is my code:

```
- (BOOL)uploadImageToTwitpic:(UIImage*)image
                 withMessage:(NSString*)theMessage
                    username:(NSString*)username
                    password:(NSString*)password
{
    NSString *stringBoundary, *contentType, *message, *baseURLString, *urlString;
    NSData *imageData;
    NSURL *url;
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest;
    NSMutableData *postBody;

    // Create POST request from message, imageData, username and password
    baseURLString = kTwitpicUploadURL;
    urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", baseURLString];
    url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    urlRequest = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease];
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    // Set the params
    message = ([theMessage length] > 1) ? theMessage : @"Here's my new Light Table collage.";
    imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, kTwitpicImageJPEGCompression);

    // Setup POST body
    stringBoundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"0xKhTmLbOuNdArY"];
    contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", stringBoundary];
    [urlRequest addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    // Setting up the POST request's multipart/form-data body
    postBody = [NSMutableData data];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n\r\n--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"source\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"lighttable"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; // So Light Table show up as source in Twitter post

    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"username\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:username] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; // username

    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"password\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:password] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; // password

    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"message\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:message] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; // message

    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"media\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", @"lighttable_twitpic_image.jpg" ] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: image/jpg\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; // jpeg as data
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:imageData]; // Tack on the imageData to the end

    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:postBody];
    NSLog(@"data=======>%@",postBody);
    NSLog(@"URLReq========>%@",urlRequest);
    // Spawn a new thread so the UI isn't blocked while we're uploading the image
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(uploadingDataWithURLRequest:) toTarget:self withObject:urlRequest];

    return YES; // TODO: Should raise exception on error
}

- (void)uploadingDataWithURLRequest:(NSURLRequest*)urlRequest {
    // Called on a separate thread; upload and handle server response

    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    [urlRequest retain]; // Retain since we autoreleased it before

    // Send the request
    NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse;
    NSError *error;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                                 returningResponse:&urlResponse
                                                             error:&error];
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData
                                                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    // Handle the error or success
    // If error, create error message and throw up UIAlertView
    NSLog(@"Response Code: %d", [urlResponse statusCode]);
    if ([urlResponse statusCode] >= 200 && [urlResponse statusCode] < 300) {
        NSLog(@"urlResultString: %@", responseString);

        NSString *match = [responseString stringByMatching:@"http[a-zA-Z0-9.:/]*"]; // Match the URL for the twitpic.com post
        NSLog(@"match: %@", match);

        // Send back notice to delegate
        [delegate twitpicEngine:self didUploadImageWithResponse:match];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Error while uploading, got 400 error back or no response at all: %@", [urlResponse statusCode]);
        [delegate twitpicEngine:self didUploadImageWithResponse:nil]; // Nil should mean "upload failed" to the delegate
    }

    [pool drain];
    [responseString release];
    [urlRequest release];
}
```

Comment: Formatted and retitled it for him.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** I suggest reading [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749630/) to see if a different way of creating the POST request helps.

---

I'm not familiar with the [Twitpic API](http://twitpic.com/api.do) myself, but I'll try to make some suggestions that can help you narrow down the problem.

The first thing I would check is the correctness of the POST body. Your code for creating that is needlessly complex and hard to read, so I wouldn't be surprised if there might be a bug in it. I'm posting a revised version (disclaimer, I haven't compiled it) that simplifies creation and improves performance. (You were creating a TON of autoreleased NSString and NSData objects, and converting strings to data every time just to append data bytes. Building up a mutable string and converting once is a much faster and simpler approach.)

In a related vein, reading through your code is a bit tough when every variable is declared at the top of the method. This is unnecessary in any recent standard of C (or derived languages) and it's considered better practice to declare variables when they are first used. Not only does it make code easier to read, but it generally trims several unnecessary lines.

Here is the code with some suggested revisions. They may make it easier to pinpoint the problem.

```
- (BOOL)uploadImageToTwitpic:(UIImage*)image
                 withMessage:(NSString*)theMessage
                    username:(NSString*)username
                    password:(NSString*)password
{
    // Create POST request from message, imageData, username and password
    NSString *baseURLString = kTwitpicUploadURL;
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", baseURLString];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease];
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    // Set the params
    NSString *message = ([theMessage length] > 1) ? theMessage : @"Here's my new Light Table collage.";

    // Setup POST body
    NSString *stringBoundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"0xKhTmLbOuNdArY"];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", stringBoundary];
    [urlRequest addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSString *stringBoundarySeparator = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", stringBoundary];

    NSMutableString *postString = [NSMutableString string];
    [postString appendString:@"\r\n"];
    [postString appendString:stringBoundarySeparator];
    [postString appendString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"source\"\r\n\r\n"];
    [postString appendString:@"lighttable"]; // So Light Table shows up as source in Twitter 
    [postString appendString:stringBoundarySeparator];
    [postString appendStringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"username\"\r\n\r\n%@", username];
    [postString appendString:stringBoundarySeparator];
    [postString appendStringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"password\"\r\n\r\n%@", password];
    [postString appendString:stringBoundarySeparator];
    [postString appendStringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"message\"\r\n\r\n%@", message];
    [postString appendString:stringBoundarySeparator];
    [postString appendStringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"media\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", @"lighttable_twitpic_image.jpg"];
    [postString appendString:@"Content-Type: image/jpg\r\n"]; // data as JPEG
    [postString appendString:@"Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n"];

    // Setting up the POST request's multipart/form-data body
    NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];
    [postBody appendData:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, kTwitpicImageJPEGCompression)]; // Tack on the image data to the end
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:postBody];
    NSLog(@"data=======>%@",postBody);
    NSLog(@"URLReq========>%@",urlRequest);
    // Spawn a new thread so the UI isn't blocked while we're uploading the image
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(uploadingDataWithURLRequest:) toTarget:self withObject:urlRequest];

    return YES; // TODO: Should raise exception on error
}

// Called on a separate thread; upload and handle server response
- (void)uploadingDataWithURLRequest:(NSURLRequest *)urlRequest {
    [urlRequest retain]; // Retain since we're using it in this method

    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    // Send the request
    NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse;
    NSError *error;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                                 returningResponse:&urlResponse
                                                             error:&error];
    NSString *responseString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData
                                                      encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];

    // Handle the error or success
    // If error, create error message and throw up UIAlertView
    NSLog(@"Response Code: %d", [urlResponse statusCode]);
    NSLog(@"Response String: %@", responseString);
    if ([urlResponse statusCode] >= 200 && [urlResponse statusCode] < 300) {
        NSString *match = [responseString stringByMatching:@"http[a-zA-Z0-9.:/]*"]; // Match the URL for the twitpic.com post
        NSLog(@"match: %@", match);
        // Send back notice to delegate
        [delegate twitpicEngine:self didUploadImageWithResponse:match];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Error while uploading, got 400 error back or no response at all: %@", [urlResponse statusCode]);
        [delegate twitpicEngine:self didUploadImageWithResponse:nil]; // Nil should mean "upload failed" to the delegate
    }
    [pool drain];
    [urlRequest release];
}
```

One thing that would help us answer your question: you state that the response code is 0, but haven't said what the rest of the response (which you record in `responseString`) is. Since you're only printing that if the status code is in the range [200,300) you may not be seeing the cause of the problem, even though Twitpic *may* be passing it back to you. It's worth checking out... (I've done this in my code above.)

Comment: https://twitpic.com/api/uploadAndPost at this URL I get response code as 0 and response data as null.So, wnat can I do for that??

Comment: I still haven't a clue — the Twitpic API should document error cases like yours. What is the status code for the response? How thoroughly have you checked your POST body against what the API expects?